# two side by side columns not aligned at same height

Tags: tables

I have to tables side by side, but the they don't begin at the same height. Is there a way to align them side by side at the top?

This is what I have so far..

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

Test Datum:

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{subtable}[t]{13.4cm}
\raggedright
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{6pt}
\begin{tabular}{|L{25mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|}
\hline
Topic 1 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 2 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 3 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 4 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 5 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 6 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 7 & & & & & & & &\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}[t]{3cm}
\raggedleft
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{6pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{|L{3cm}|}
\hline
Material \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Here is a picture
[image]

Update !!!

Now they are aligned at the top but the space to the edges of the document is not the same for the two tables

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

Test Datum:

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{table}[htb]

\raggedright
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{6pt}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|L{25mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|}
\firsthline
Topic 1 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 2 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 3 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 4 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 5 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 6 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 7 & & & & & & & &\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\raggedleft
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{6pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|L{3cm}|}
\firsthline
Material \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `subtable`, which is used when you have to add subcaptions.

Use the `[t]` optional argument, but note `\firsthline`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

Test Datum:

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{subtable}[t]{13.4cm}
\raggedright
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{6pt}
\begin{tabular}{|L{25mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|L{5mm}|}
\firsthline
Topic 1 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 2 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 3 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 4 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 5 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 6 & & & & & & & &\\
Topic 7 & & & & & & & &\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}[t]{3cm}
\raggedleft
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{6pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{|L{3cm}|}
\firsthline
Material \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
$\bullet$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You possibly don't need `table`, but just a `flushleft` environment.

[image]

Comment: As you suggested I deleted the subtables and added \firsthline. Now they are aligned at the same height  but they aren't aligned in the center... on the left side there´s more space to the edge of the document. pls see update..

Comment: Deleted also the table environement and now it works perfectly!